# Vscode for python jupyter fail to show video

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make a animation in the Jupyter of Visual Studio Code. The code is listed below.

```
import arviz as az
from IPython.display import HTML
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
...
...
...
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(bins.shape[0]),
                 init_func=init, blit=True, interval=20)
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

However, the Jupyter fail to play the video on the Visual Studio Code. The result was shown in the picture below. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also getting this issue. I've used [this](http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-as-interactive-javascript-widgets/) animation tutorial to confirm it was an VSCode issue and not my code, which I'd confirmed works in vanilla Jupyter.

I've installed [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html) for use with this code sample since it's easy enough to set up.

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab` (or `pip install jupyterlab`)

`jupyter lab`

Executing the run command from the directory with your resources with default that as the run location of Jupyter so you shouldn't need to alter your code. Here's hoping they resolve this soon.

Comment: Unfortunately, they probably won't fix this in the near future https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11583